# What is SDK Emulation

Tags: nokia

Can anyone tell me what is SDK Emulation

Answer (score 1):

SDK Emulation is a technique that mimics all of the hardware and software features of a device (say mobile) so that you can prototype, develop, and test applications without using a physical device. For example for Android you can refer: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: @suthasankar: I want to check for nokiaN97. i download it. But i don know how to test my webpage in that emulation

Comment: Check any firewall preventing the access. Refer Nokia Emulators section in http://mobiforge.com/testing/story/a-guide-mobile-emulators